# Why does Load image work on emulator but not on s4?

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I'm trying to get an image to load onto my app in an imageview. However whenever I try it on my S4 (running 4.4.2) once I tap on the image I want to load. it says 'Unfortunately, E-textHome has stopped.'. But when I try the app on my emulator, which is a Nexus7 (running 4.1.3) It works perfectly fine. So I was wondering what have I done wrong and how do I make it work on my s4? Thanks!

Code:-

```
public class EncryptImg extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private static int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.encryptimg);

        Button galleryBrowse =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.browseGallerybtn1);
        galleryBrowse.setOnClickListener(this); /*Set OnClickListener for to listen for the galerryBrowse button*/

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.browseGallerybtn1){
            Intent loadImgIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); 
            startActivityForResult(loadImgIntent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ImageView imgEncrypt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.encryptImgView);

        // http://www.itcuties.com/android/pick-image-from-gallery/.

        if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            // Let's read picked image data - its URI
            Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
            // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

            // Now we need to set the GUI ImageView data with data read from the picked file.
            imgEncrypt.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));

            // At the end remember to close the cursor or you will end with the RuntimeException!
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

}
```

XML file:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/browseGallerybtn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Browse Gallery" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/encryptImgView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the LogCat. There you will find the error/exception and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that app is working on emulator then it has to do something with Permissions in your manifest file. Make sure you have given all required permissions like 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' etc.

Comment: Your an absolute star, as If I didn't do that.Thank you!